# Uninstall/Clear IE ActiveX Addon programatically (win32)

Tags: com, activex, cab, inf, ieaddon

I'm trying to clean up the traces left by an ActiveX IE Addon. The Addon (COM DLL) was installed using a cab file.

Manually, IE -> Manage Add-ons -> open the addon and REMOVE is also not helping. It clears the addon from IE but registry traces are left behind!
Also, it throws a Runtime Error!

> Program: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\EInstal.exe
>
> R6034: An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.

So, I presume the inf file used for installation doesn't have the info to uninstall the addon properly. Am I right? (contents in %alluserappdata%)

**What happens internally when an add-on is removed from IE?**
- Does it use the inf file? Or does it try to call the UnregisterServer call in the registered DLL?

Look forward to your help.

Comment: Hey all,
Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleared all the registry entries left behind using [Registry funcions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Couldn't find any other solution. The cab file generated did not have any information in the ini file to uninstall the Add-on.